# Google Drive encrypt image with Apps Script? (cCryptoGS)

Tags: image, encryption, google-apps-script

So my company is green-lighting a project where we will be working with confidential images stored in Google Drive. We have the drive set to just a few people, but I've been asked to make a web app in Google Apps Script so users can access the data from there without knowing it's actually stored on Drive.

I feel a little uncomfortable that we have jpegs and pngs of sensitive information on a Team Drive in our GSuite domain. I'd rather store the images in an encrypted format instead if possible.

I discovered an AES encryption library [named](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/cryptogs) [CryptoGS](https://script.google.com/d/1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs/edit?usp=sharing) (A Derivative of the mainstream JavaScript library [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)) That seems to work fine with text and such. I was hoping to leverage it to create encrypted versions of google Drive files and decrypt them only in my webapp. That way the files would be useless if an insider went rogue and downloaded the date from Google drive to sell to a competitor.

Here is my test code to see if I can run a two-way encryption scheme. You can run the same code yourself by creating your own code on script.google.com and adding the library MSJnPeIon6nzdLewGV60xWqi_d-phDA33 (Instructions on how to add a library [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries))

```js
function TestEncryption()
{
  //Add library MSJnPeIon6nzdLewGV60xWqi_d-phDA33 to project to access CryptoGS functions
  
  var hash = "This is my secret passphrase";  
  var cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(hash, 'aes');

  var origFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of an example file");
  
  var blob = origFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  
  var encryptedBlob = cipher.encrypt(blob);
  
  var encryptedFile = DriveApp.createFile("ENCRYPTEDTest", encryptedBlob);
  
  var newBlob = encryptedFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  
  var decryptedBlob = cipher.decrypt(newBlob);
  
  var decryptedFile = DriveApp.createFile("DECRYPTEDTest", decryptedBlob);
  
  
}
```

Basically, after testing on a .GIF file, I get a scrambled file named ENCRYPTEDTest, and an image file named DECRYPTEDTest that is corrupted and unusable even after downloading to my desktop. Would it be an easy fix to adapt this encryption method to successfully secure images on Google Drive?

Comment: Are the "users" part of your company?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Cooper: Yes, all the users are internal employees who have granted permission for us to work with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that when the binary data is directly used, the corruption of data might occur. So how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Use the byte array instead of the blob.

  - Modify from `getBlob().getDataAsString()` to `getBytes().toString()`.
- When the data is decoded, the number values are converted to the byte array, and converted to the blob.

I think that there are several workarounds. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modified script:

```
function TestEncryption()
{
  //Add library MSJnPeIon6nzdLewGV60xWqi_d-phDA33 to project to access CryptoGS functions

  var hash = "This is my secret passphrase";
  var cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(hash, 'aes');

  // Encode
  var origFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID of an example file");
  var mimeType = origFile.getMimeType(); // Added
  var blob = origFile.getBlob().getBytes().toString(); // Modified
  var encryptedBlob = cipher.encrypt(blob);
  var encryptedFile = DriveApp.createFile("ENCRYPTEDTest", encryptedBlob);
  var newBlob = encryptedFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();

  // Decode
  var decryptedBlob = cipher.decrypt(newBlob);
  var b = Utilities.newBlob(decryptedBlob.split(","), mimeType, "DECRYPTEDTest"); // Added
  var decryptedFile = DriveApp.createFile(b); // Modified
}
```

#### References:

- [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getBytes())
- [newBlob(data, contentType, name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newBlob(Byte,String,String))

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: It Worked! Great Job Tanaike! Never thought to use MimeType to protect integrity of the bytes.

Comment: @Nathaniel MacIver Thank you for your response.

Comment: I just tryed this code with an Excel file stored in Drive and it worked perfectly.